# what is the fastest method to generate matrix of data type float?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to generate a 10000*10000 matrix of data type float with non zero entries using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
list_going_in=np.random.rand(10000,10000)
```

but it takes more than a second to generate is there a faster method than this to do it.

appreciate your help.

Comment: Use `np.empty()`?

Comment: @Divakar but it only has zeros in it , I will like to have random float numbers in it

Comment: Unless you store the random numbers in advance and use the same ones everytime, no.

Comment: Do you need random numbers or non-zero numbers? `np.empty()` returns non-initialized array, which means "whatever was there before".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no faster way to do this. The overhead of random number generation is limiting you. The only way to optimize these things is if there is some structure to the matrix (like everything 0, or  triangle, or sparse, etc...). If every cell is different, you have to calculate and store each one separately.

`np.random` may be the fastest as far as I know, and is close in any case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it possible that I generate an empty matrix and then perform an operation to have it include random numbers (e.g. multiplication or addition etc?

Comment: @RohitSharma I am afraid that would be slower. Write a `c` program that loops through 10000^2 iterations and generates random numbers - you will see it is not far off. `numpy` is almost always the fastest way to go in numerical methods.

Comment: Unless by "include" you mean not all of the matrix but a small subset? Then it  is possible.

Comment: please suggest  what it can be if a subset is non empty atleast

Comment: @RohitSharma That is not the way to work in SO. This answers your original question and it is impolite to change it now. If you would like, accept this, and write another question detailing exactly what you need done, otherwise I would be guessing. I suggest in your new question you write your end-goal as well (check out [xy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: Link it in the comments here if you would like me to take a look.

Comment: Can you please suggest the method that you were talking about?

Comment: @RohitSharma Of course, but this question is not good as it is written - and I do not know what you want. You have a specific goal in mind - Ask a new question, write your goal what exactly you need of the matrix, and why the solution you used (`rand`) does not work. I do not know what you want to do, you need to write it down properly.

Answer (score 2):

you can use empty for this purpose:

for example something like:

```
np.empty((1000,1000))+np.empty((1000))
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken the use of such situations only arise when you are developing neural networks, may I suggest that you use tensor-flow:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.random_uniform(
    shape,
    minval=0,
    maxval=None,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    seed=None,
    name=None
)
```